# I cant remove duplicate post from mn_postmeta, need SQL advice

Tags: sql, insert, sql-delete

I ran the provided SQL command on my websites SQL database
and accidentally posted the same data twice, now I want to remove what I posted

I tried using a Delete From command but it did not work, maybe my syntax was wrong

```
INSERT INTO `mn_postmeta` (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES (24410,'_clinician-publications-year','2019~~~Umer A, Loudin S, <b>Maxwell S</b>, Lilly C, Stabler ME, Cottrell L, Hamilton C, Breyel, Mullins C, John C. Capturing the statewide incidence of neonatal abstinence syndrome in real-time: the West Virginia experience. Pediatr Res. 2019 Apr. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30287893');
```

I want to remove the duplicate post-data so that the post data shows once on the website.

Comment: I tried this
`
DELETE FROM `mn_postmeta`  WHERE (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) = (24410,'_clinician-publications-year','2019~~~Umer A, Loudin S, <b>Maxwell S</b>, Lilly C, Stabler M, Cottrell L, Hamilton C, Breyel, Mullins C, John C. Capturing the statewide incidence of neonatal abstinence syndrome in real time: the West Virginia experience. Pediatr Res. 2019 Apr. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30287893');
` no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i never selected the correct table 
i was able to delete the duplicate, the above DElETE FROM command works for removing duplicate post data